# mls cef maximum-routes

Tags: juniper, cef

```
Cisco#show mls cef maximum-routes
FIB TCAM maximum routes :
=======================
Current :-
-------
 IPv4                - 1000k 
 MPLS                - 8k (default)
 IPv6 + IP Multicast - 8k (default)
```

I need to know the maximum forwarding-table routes supported in Juniper MX960.
What's the command ?
Thanks

Comment: By the way, you can change the Cisco allocation, e.g. more IPv4 and less IPv6 routes.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is no equivalent command in the JunOS CLI that I'm aware of however it's going to be based on the MPC you are using for the forwarding table.  I don't know that Juniper ever gives actual hard limits but I may be able to find the "soft" numbers if you tell me which MPCs you are using.

Comment: Here are the numbers I've found for the more common MPCs

Comment: MPC 1, MPC2  - 5M 
MPC2-NG, MPC3-NG, MPC5 - 10M